# What is proper method to load XDocument from Azure Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to move all my file retrieval for my site to Azure storage (supposedly to make retrieving files less error prone due to path issues). This was/is not as easy as it sounded. I am able to get to the storage account and container and load the blob into a variable but I cannot find any way to get the contents into an XDocument. I've tried almost every method associated with files that shows under the intellisense for my blob variable.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azurestorageconn"]);
        var client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        //create a blob container with public accessibility
        var sampleContainer = client.GetContainerReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azurecontainer"]);
        sampleContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
        sampleContainer.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions()
        {
            PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
        });
        var blob = sampleContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(@"files\" + NavXmlFile);
        XDocument xDoc;
        //tried almost everything here
        using (var xml = blob.OpenRead())
        {
             xDoc = XDocument.Load(xml);
        }

        Assert.IsNotNull(xDoc);
    }
```

I can't seem to find any examples of loading xml file content into XDocument or XElement anywhere on the web or here on SO. Any help appreciated.

Not that it should matter but here is a sample of the xml document.

```
<Menus>
  <Menu>
    <MenuId>1</MenuId>
    <ParentMenuId>0</ParentMenuId>
    <MenuTitle>Home</MenuTitle>
    <DisplayOrder>10</DisplayOrder>
    <MenuAction>/Home/Index</MenuAction>
    <MenuRoles></MenuRoles>
 </Menu>
 <Menu>
   <MenuId>2</MenuId>
   <ParentMenuId>0</ParentMenuId>
   <MenuTitle>Languages</MenuTitle>
   <DisplayOrder>20</DisplayOrder>
   <MenuAction></MenuAction>
   <MenuRoles></MenuRoles>
 </Menu>
</Menus>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri...I wouldm't have posted otherwise, An Azure storage exception on the xml=blob.OpenRead line. Which is where the error occurs regardless of what method I try to pull the content. In this particular instance the error is Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. ...Which males no sense because examining blob you can see it holds the xml from the file I am requesting.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the error details. 404 error means that blob was not found. I noticed that this is how you're referencing the blob: `var blob = sampleContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(@"files\" + NavXmlFile);`. Can you change that to something like: `var blob = sampleContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(@"files/" + NavXmlFile);`? If you notice, I changed "\" to "/". Give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: The error makes no sense, after stepping past var blob = sampleContainer... And examining blob, it does contain the xml from the file, it's the loading that xml into the xml variable that's failing, whether I try a stream, text download or whatever. I will try your suggestion and comment again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the easiest way, as it turns out, is to just load the url path into an XElement, as long as the files are publicly accessible. It just requires having the url path to your Azure file hard coded into your program somewhere. This is probably problematic if you have hundreds of files to use this for.

```
var filepath = "yourazurefilesurlpath"
var doc = XElement.Load(filepath);
```

I would still like to know how to do it using the method I have in the original post.

**Update:**

Here is how to do it programatically

```
var blob = AzureStorageMethods.GetAzureBlob(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["publicfiles"], NavXmlFile);
var doc = XElement.Load(blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
```

And here is the code for the blob call

```
public static CloudBlockBlob GetAzureBlob(string containername,string filename)
    {
        var creds = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azurestorageconn"];
        var azureStorage = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(creds);
        var client = azureStorage.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        //create a blob container and make it publicly accessibile
        var baseContainer = client.GetContainerReference(containername);  
        baseContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
        baseContainer.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions()
        {
            PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
        });
        var blob = baseContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
        return blob;
    }
```

Comment: This solution would work only if the blob in the question is publicly accessible (i.e. the container containing the blob has `Blob` or `Container` ACL). If the container ACL is `Private`, then your code would fail as anonymous requests won't succeed in this case. BTW, did you try the solution I mentioned in my comment?

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri...I tried your solution, that did not work. The files I need to load into XElement are all public so for that particular application, it works as needed. I am having another issue loading text files, please see my post here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018775/azure-blob-url-comes-back-incorrectly-for-text-file-load