# Azure blob URL comes back incorrectly for text file load

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

Herein lies my problem, the working path to the file I am trying to load into a string variable, when copied from Azure Explorer works fine.

> Working: https://container.blob.core.windows.net/files/emailtemplates/EmailMaster.html

When I try to do it via code:

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod3()
    {
        string templateHtml;
        var blob = AzureStorageMethods.GetAzureBlob(AzureFileFolder + "EmailMaster.html");
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            blob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
            templateHtml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
        Assert.AreNotEqual(0, templateHtml.Length);
    }
```

Here is the code for GetAzureBlob:

```
 public static CloudBlockBlob GetAzureBlob(string filename)
    {
        var creds = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azurestorageconn"];
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(creds);
        var client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        //create a blob container and make it publicly accessibile
        var sampleContainer = client.GetContainerReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azurecontainer"]);
        sampleContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
        sampleContainer.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions()
        {
            PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
        });
        var blob = sampleContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(@"files\" + filename);
        return blob;
    }
```

It fails to Download the stream because the endpoint path is wrong.
It comes back as

> Not Working: https://container.blob.core.windows.net/container/files/emailtemplates/EmailMaster.html

Note that my method to return a blob, has the container as part of the url, whereas the path from azure explorer does not.

I can't see any way to solve this. I've tried accessing the files container directly but I'm either doing it wrong or it isn't doable.

The directory tree (even though there technically isn't one in Azure) is mystorageaccountname/files/emailtemplates/filename. Any solutions appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the code for AzureStorageMethods.GetAzureBlob()? I suspect there's something missing there.

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri...Sorry about that, I meant to include that in the original post. It is there now.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code. A few questions: 1) What's the name of your container? 2) When you look at the blobs in your container, are they under "files" folder in that container? 3) Your URL lists `container.blob.core.windows.net/container`. I am guessing the 1st `container` refers to the account name. Am I correct?

Comment: correct, I replaced the azure storage account name with 'container'. The account name was in both places where container is now. The second one is whats wrong with the url retured in the blob

Comment: One thing that is confusing me is from where you're getting `emailtemplates` in your path? You're specifying it nowhere. All I can see is that you're expecting a file called `EmailMaster.html` in `files` folder in your blob container. Can you please clarify that? Also please tell me the answer for 1) and 2) above. Thanks.

Comment: private const string AzureFileFolder = @"emailtemplates/"; is a const in the test class

Comment: Thanks! What is the name of your container? Is it `files`?

Comment: See the last line of my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change this line of code:

```
var blob = sampleContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(@"files\" + filename);
```

to

```
var blob = sampleContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
```

Based on your note:

> The directory tree (even though there technically isn't one in Azure)
>   is mystorageaccountname/files/emailtemplates/filename.

It is my understanding that the name of your container is `files`. When you use `container.GetBlockBlobReference` construct, you don't need to specify the container name again in the name parameter. It will be taken care of by the library.

Comment: I just figured that out, ty